# how to measure height, width and distance of object using camera in phone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Can anyone give me/suggest me the right way or any example so that I can get more idea about this requirement.

i will try trigonometric but height is not get from the capture object/wall. please ,help me solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's not possible, since iOS devices don't have such sensors. No echo-locators, no even second rear camera for getting stereo image and using paralax effect for analyzing distance. You have only flat 2d image.